# Checar si AJAX si esta ejecutando y esperar a que termine

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo una pagina con varios botones. Todos los botones mandan ejecutar la misma funcion, la cual ejecuta el mismo AJAX (aunque con diferente `data` para cada caso).

En `beforeSend` remuevo la tabla que se este mostrando actualmente mediante su `id` (siempre genero la tabla con el mismo `id`).

En `.done()` reconstruyo la tabla usando la respuesta del servidor.

Hasta aquí todo en orden. Sin embargo, si el usuario presiona un botón, y luego presiona otro cuando el primero aún no ha terminado, el resultado es que se me generan dos tablas.

La solución temporal que he aplicado es remover la tabla tanto en el `beforeSend` como en el `.done()`.

¿Es posible checar de alguna manera si la primera ejecución del AJAX ha terminado?¿O como puedo hacer para que la segunda ejecución AJAX espere a que termine la primera?

Comment: Buen Día, te recomiendo que leas [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  y edites tu pregunta para que agregues tu código en texto, de lo que tienes, lo que recibes y lo que esperas.

Answer (score 0):

Usualmente utilizo una variable comodín que varía su valor cuando se ejecuta una función asíncrona y cuando se termina. De esta manera evito la superposición de llamadas.

```
let flag = true;

function xhr(){
    if (flag){ //Si el comodín es true
        flag = false; //Cambia a false, evitando que otras llamadas se ejecuten
        $.ajax({...})
            .done(function(){
                //Cuando se completa la actual llamada, cambia el valor a true
                flag = true;
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomiendo es usar el objeto Promise, el cual, espera hasta que este se termine de ejecutar.

Te adjunto el enlace para que le eches un ojo. [Objeto Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)